# Media queries not working in Safari but in IE, Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css, safari, media-queries

I've got a quite strange error and I seriously can't figure out what I did wrong.

Currently I am working on a responsive website project with media queries.
After weeks of working I just realized that my media queries are not working in Safari but everywhere else.

Some examples of my CSS

```
@media (max-width: 1138px) {
  .column-2 {max-width: 32.4%;}
}

@media (max-width: 950px) { 
  .column-2, .column-1 {
    max-width: 17.9%;border-left:1px solid #e5e5e5;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 640px) {
  .column-2, .column-1 {
    max-width:100%; 
    border-bottom:1px solid #e5e5e5; 
    height:20%; 
    width: 91%;
  } 
  footer div.left, footer div.right {
    width:100% !important;
  }
}
```

Viewport Added in HTML head section

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I've also tried with `@media screen only and (...) {}`. Still not working.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `screen only and` is not valid. It should be `only screen and`

Comment: Hm, I tried `only screen an` but it's still not working in Safari. Only in IE, Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: can you add it in fiddle? at least a basic version of the page you are doing

Comment: Here is a basic version of my page http://jsfiddle.net/67wdC/3/

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Answer (score 2):

Your first breakpoint is missing the closing bracket after "max-width: 32.4%".

Comment: It's been edited so the closing bracket is in place now, edit it and vote me down for trying to help, classy....

Comment: Thanks for update, don't worry about it, not going to lose sleep over it. Hope you get sorted anyway! (my rep has been damaged by this, oh what a cruel world.....)

Comment: @polarcare agree I don't think it was needed to be downvoted since you saw an error...though it was not the issue...I upvoted for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the fix but it looks like you're missing a closing bracket after "32.4%" and possibly the "screen" part of your media query. You're not defining the range of what the media query handles. Here's a sample of a media query I wrote on a website I did (http://bonjourproject.com/):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {  
     .bottom {
    width: 400px;
  }
}
```

be sure to add "screen and" and see if that works for you.

Note: "screen" is not the only option here there are many more to choose from, but "screen" is pretty common. Let me know if this works!

Comment: Hm okay I added 'screen and', like `@media screen and (max-width: 1138px) {

    .column-2 {max-width: 32.4%;}
}` but still not working... Safari still doesn't accept any breakpoint. What I found out, on the iPad it's working only in the portrait mode but not in landscape.

Comment: alrighty, have you just tried "<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">" without the initial scale just to see if it would work. It seems like a lot of people are having this problem, and the solution usually falls into an improper meta tag.

Comment: Also for my site I used the meta tag "<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0>" It would be extremely weird for the .0 to be the problem but it's worth a shot?

Comment: tried both with initial-scale=1.0 and without initial-scale...still nothing changed. My meta tags are `<meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>X-Cell</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        `

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the full stack of your css/html  there are many possibilities why this is happening but since its working on the other browsers and not iOS go and try adding this just to test and see if Safari picks it up:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    /* put webkit CSS here*/
}
```

If still nothing then you need to check you html head syntax and css tag make sure there is no typo...try using console. This will at least help me/everyone figure what other steps you need. and as I mentioned try adding something basic in fiddle for us.